# How can I make Shiny to remember various choices from multiple selectInputs

Tags: shiny

I have below `Shiny-app` which houses 2 `selectInput()`

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("A" = "A",
                  "B" = "B",
                  "C" = "C")),
    uiOutput("moreControls")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$moreControls <-  renderUI({
            Choice = input$variable
            if (Choice == 'A') Result = c('X1', 'X2', 'X3')
            if (Choice == 'B') Result = c('Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3')
            if (Choice == 'C') Result = c('Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3')

            selectInput("variable1", "Variable-1:", Result)
      })
  }
)
```

Now let say, when `variable = 'A'` user chooses `'X2'`. Now User go to `variable = 'C'` to pick up one value from there let say it is `'Z3'`. Here, the problem is when user move from `'A'` to `'C'`, his 1st choice `'X2'` is not retained for further downstream calculation.

How can make `Shiny` remember that what User had chosen from other elements of selectInput and collectively pass all such choices for downstream calculation? All calculation and choices are confined in a single session.

Comment: Do you always want the user to choose of each x,y, and z values? If so, I would get rid of the if statements and add 3 different uiOutputs instead.

Comment: This is for classification purpose. Let say I have 3 equity classes viz Banking, Agri, and others, within each class I have multiple equity names. I think for user, such classification is more informative. I could add 3 different uiOutputs, however I have so many classes in my actual scenario, totaling 20. So putting so many different uiOutputs, will make my App very noisy

Answer (score -1):

You should consider implementing [modular shiny code](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) for your select input object.

After you've written the module, you may call it however many times you need, as long as you provide a unique ID each time.

Comment: This is not an answer, most suitably it should go as adding comment